# why DolphinDB reports error message when subscribing to stream tables

Tags: stream, subscription, dolphindb

I subscribed to stream tables in DolphinDB, but the error reports ‘exception=Only a table can append to another table’. Is there anything wrong with my code?
I also used a user-defined function as the handler. Still, the error message ‘exception=FROM clause must return a table’ shows up.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When subscribing to the stream table, you need to specify the parameter ‘msgAsTable=true’.

```
subscribeTable(tableName="trades1", actionName="tradesStats22", offset=0, handler=func, msgAsTable=true)
```

Its default value is false, meaning the subscribed data is ingested into handler as a tuple of columns. That's the cause for the two errors.